# I want to define foreign key between two or more tables

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I tried lots of things but it didn't work. Let me use what I did:

[image]

And this table : 
[image]

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cmpe`.`#sql-2068_94` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint i
>   s incorrectly formed")

Can you please help me?

Comment: All your id's need to be integer and unsigned. In advance post code here instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your foreign fields need to be int instead of string. Also make them unsigned. That is the correct format to create the foreign key.

An example:

```
$table->integer('myForeignID')->unsigned();
```

This lines can be removed as it is most likely not required:

```
$table->foreign('year')->references('id')->on('course');
$table->foreign('semester')->references('id')->on('course');
```

Also render the tables course and instructors before table posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('instructors_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('year')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('semester')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('body');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('instructors_id')->references('id')->on('instructors');
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('course');
        $table->foreign('year')->references('id')->on('course');
        $table->foreign('semester')->references('id')->on('course');

    });
}


public function up()
{
     Schema::create('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->integer('semester');
        $table->integer('year');
    });
}
```